# Inner div with 100% is spilling out of outer div

Tags: html, css

When setting up below css, I got the cellContentResult out of the container div.
So lets say my whole div is `820px`, so the whole row should have this size. But unfortunatelly the cellContentResult has 820px as well, even when rest of the div's taking lets say `200px`, so the whole site has `1020px`.

```css
.list {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  height: 3.8em;
  width: 100%;
}

.defaultCellContent {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.cellContentDate {
  width: 8.5em;
}

.cellContentName {
  text-align: center;
  width: 5em;
}

.cellContentResult {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cellContentIcon defaultCellContent"></div>
    <div class="cellContentDate defaultCellContent">
      <div>2019-01-28 06:45:33</div>
      <div>2019-01-28 06:45:43</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cellContentName defaultCellContent">
      <div class="name">task1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cellContentResult defaultCellContent">
      <div class="result">Finished</div>
      <div class="message">Message TESTTESTEST</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @FrankFajardo I would like to avoid that issue. Because I might to want add text overflow to that styles. And because text is expanding out of the site I wont be able to do that.

Comment: You are assigning `width:100%` to `cellContentResult` so naturally, it will try to occupy the width of the containing block. You may want to understand how to set [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width).

Comment: @FrankFajardo You are probably right, but I thought that when I set constant value for other columns(contents) with em, CSS will calculate for me what is 100% for the cellContentResult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hint from @FrankFajardo I was able to achieve it with something like this:

```
.cellContentResult {
  width: calc(100% - 18em);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using `flex` on the row you can use `flex: 1` on `.cellContentResult` since it is the only non-fixed width cell. This will allow it to grow or shrink to occupy the remaining available space.

```css
.list{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.row {
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    height: 3.8em;
    width: 100%;
}

.defaultCellContent {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.cellContentDate {
    width: 8.5em;
}

.cellContentName {
    text-align: center;
    width: 5em;
}

.cellContentResult {
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cellContentIcon defaultCellContent"></div> 
        <div class="cellContentDate defaultCellContent">
            <div>2019-01-28 06:45:33</div> 
            <div>2019-01-28 06:45:43</div> 
        </div> 
        <div class="cellContentName defaultCellContent"> 
            <div class="name">task1</div> 
        </div> 
        <div class="cellContentResult defaultCellContent"> 
            <div class="result">Finished</div> 
            <div class="message">Message TESTTESTEST</div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

as you display as 'table' the list, I'd display as 'table-row' the '.row' and display 'table-cell' the '.defaultCellContent'.
Like this:

```
<style>
.list {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row {
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table-row;
    height: 3.8em;
    width: 100%;
}

.defaultCellContent {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}

.defaultCellContent div {
    padding: 2px 0;
}

.cellContentDate {
    width: 8.5em;
}

.cellContentName {
    text-align: center;
    width: 5em;
}

.cellContentResult {
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

"You have to set your row class height auto; then you will get the exact what you want."

```
.row {
transition: all .2s ease-out;
overflow: hidden;
display: flex;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
```

}